# Converting PL/SQL function to PL/pgSQL

Tags: plsql, plpgsql

The following is a 5 minute problem of mine and I shouldn't have invested as much time in this as I did.
I need to write a normal CDF in plpqsql, but I am still baffled by the syntax. The plsql normal CDF is defined here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StdNormalDistributionCDF_3] ( @x FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Z FLOAT = ABS(@x)/SQRT(2.0);
DECLARE @Z2 FLOAT = @Z*@Z; -- optimization

IF (@Z >=11.0) -- value is too large no need to compute
BEGIN
  IF @x > 0.0
    RETURN 1.0;
  RETURN 0.0;
END

-- Compute ERF using W. J. Cody 1969

DECLARE @ERF FLOAT;

IF (@Z <= 0.46786)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pA0 FLOAT = 3.209377589138469472562E03;
  DECLARE @pA1 FLOAT = 3.774852376853020208137E02;
  DECLARE @pA2 FLOAT = 1.138641541510501556495E02;
  DECLARE @pA3 FLOAT = 3.161123743870565596947E00;
  DECLARE @pA4 FLOAT = 1.857777061846031526730E-01;

  DECLARE @qA0 FLOAT = 2.844236833439170622273E03;
  DECLARE @qA1 FLOAT = 1.282616526077372275645E03;
  DECLARE @qA2 FLOAT = 2.440246379344441733056E02;
  DECLARE @qA3 FLOAT = 2.360129095234412093499E01;
  DECLARE @qA4 FLOAT = 1.000000000000000000000E00;

  -- For efficiency compute sequence of powers of @Z 
  -- (instead of calling POWER(@Z,2), POWER(@Z,4), etc.)
  DECLARE @ZA4 FLOAT = @Z2*@Z2;
  DECLARE @ZA6 FLOAT = @ZA4*@Z2;
  DECLARE @ZA8 FLOAT = @ZA6*@Z2;


  SELECT @ERF = @Z *
    (@pA0 + @pA1*@Z2 + @pA2*@ZA4 + @pA3*@ZA6 + @pA4*@ZA8) /
    (@qA0 + @qA1*@Z2 + @qA2*@ZA4 + @qA3*@ZA6 + @qA4*@ZA8);
END
ELSE IF (@Z <= 4.0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pB0 FLOAT = 1.23033935479799725272E03;
  DECLARE @pB1 FLOAT = 2.05107837782607146532E03;
  DECLARE @pB2 FLOAT = 1.71204761263407058314E03;
  DECLARE @pB3 FLOAT = 8.81952221241769090411E02;
  DECLARE @pB4 FLOAT = 2.98635138197400131132E02;
  DECLARE @pB5 FLOAT = 6.61191906371416294775E01;
  DECLARE @pB6 FLOAT = 8.88314979438837594118E00;
  DECLARE @pB7 FLOAT = 5.64188496988670089180E-01;
  DECLARE @pB8 FLOAT = 2.15311535474403846343E-08;

  DECLARE @qB0 FLOAT = 1.23033935480374942043E03;
  DECLARE @qB1 FLOAT = 3.43936767414372163696E03;
  DECLARE @qB2 FLOAT = 4.36261909014324715820E03;
  DECLARE @qB3 FLOAT = 3.29079923573345962678E03;
  DECLARE @qB4 FLOAT = 1.62138957456669018874E03;
  DECLARE @qB5 FLOAT = 5.37181101862009857509E02;
  DECLARE @qB6 FLOAT = 1.17693950891312499305E02;
  DECLARE @qB7 FLOAT = 1.57449261107098347253E01;
  DECLARE @qB8 FLOAT = 1.00000000000000000000E00;

  -- For efficiency compute sequence of powers of @Z 
  -- (instead of calling POWER(@Z,2), POWER(@Z,3), etc.)
  DECLARE @ZB3 FLOAT = @Z2*@Z;
  DECLARE @ZB4 FLOAT = @ZB3*@Z;
  DECLARE @ZB5 FLOAT = @ZB4*@Z;
  DECLARE @ZB6 FLOAT = @ZB5*@Z;
  DECLARE @ZB7 FLOAT = @ZB6*@Z;
  DECLARE @ZB8 FLOAT = @ZB7*@Z;

  SELECT @ERF = 1.0 - EXP(-@Z2) *
          (@pB0 + @pB1*@Z + @pB2*@Z2 + @pB3*@ZB3 + @pB4*@ZB4
           + @pB5*@ZB5 + @pB6*@ZB6 + @pB7*@ZB7 + @pB8*@ZB8) /
          (@qB0 + @qB1*@Z + @qB2*@Z2 + @qB3*@ZB3 + @qB4*@ZB4
           + @qB5*@ZB5 + @qB6*@ZB6 + @qB7*@ZB7 + @qB8*@ZB8);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  DECLARE @pC0 FLOAT = -6.58749161529837803157E-04;
  DECLARE @pC1 FLOAT = -1.60837851487422766278E-02;
  DECLARE @pC2 FLOAT = -1.25781726111229246204E-01;
  DECLARE @pC3 FLOAT = -3.60344899949804439429E-01;
  DECLARE @pC4 FLOAT = -3.05326634961232344035E-01;
  DECLARE @pC5 FLOAT = -1.63153871373020978498E-02;

  DECLARE @qC0 FLOAT = 2.33520497626869185443E-03;
  DECLARE @qC1 FLOAT = 6.05183413124413191178E-02;
  DECLARE @qC2 FLOAT = 5.27905102951428412248E-01;
  DECLARE @qC3 FLOAT = 1.87295284992346047209E00;
  DECLARE @qC4 FLOAT = 2.56852019228982242072E00;
  DECLARE @qC5 FLOAT = 1.00000000000000000000E00;

  DECLARE @pi FLOAT = 3.141592653589793238462643383;

  -- For efficiency compute sequence of powers of @Z 
  -- (instead of calling POWER(@Z,-2), POWER(@Z,-3), etc.)
  DECLARE @ZC2 FLOAT = (1/@Z)/@Z;
  DECLARE @ZC4 FLOAT = @ZC2*@ZC2;
  DECLARE @ZC6 FLOAT = @ZC4*@ZC2;
  DECLARE @ZC8 FLOAT = @ZC6*@ZC2;
  DECLARE @ZC10 FLOAT = @ZC8*@ZC2;

  SELECT @ERF = 1 - EXP(-@Z2)/@Z * (1/SQRT(@pi) + 1/(@Z2)*
         ((@pC0 + @pC1*@ZC2 + @pC2*@ZC4 + @pC3*@ZC6 + @pC4*@ZC8 + @pC5*@ZC10) /
          (@qC0 + @qC1*@ZC2 + @qC2*@ZC4 + @qC3*@ZC6 + @qC4*@ZC8 + @qC5*@ZC10)));
END

DECLARE @cd FLOAT = 0.5*(1+@ERF);

IF @x > 0
  RETURN @cd;

RETURN 1.0-@cd;
END`
```

My try at converting it looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION StdNormalDistributionCDF (x double precision)
RETURNS double precision
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE
AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
    DECLARE Z FLOAT = ABS(x)/SQRT(2.0);
    DECLARE Z2 FLOAT = Z*Z; -- optimization

    IF (Z >=11.0) then -- value is too large no need to compute
    BEGIN
      IF x > 0.0
        RETURN 1.0;
      RETURN 0.0;
    END 
``
```

Now this yields the following error:

```
**ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 31:     IF (Z >=11.0) then **
```

I can't exactly figure out what I am doing wrong... My background is python/c

Comment: Do not post a link to code. Paste it into the question. The linked code also appears to be T-SQL at least it isn't PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `IF` is

```
IF <condition> THEN
  <statements>
END IF;
```

*not*

```
IF <condition> THEN
BEGIN
  <statements>
END
```

Parenthesis around the condition aren't needed BTW.

And variable declaration is done in in a `DECLARE` block that precedes the `BEGIN`.

So from the syntactical point of view your code should read:

```
...
DECLARE
  Z float = abs(x) / sqrt(2.0);
  Z2 float = Z * Z;
  ...
BEGIN
  IF Z >= 11.0 THEN
    IF x > 0.0 THEN
      RETURN 1.0;
    END IF;
    RETURN 0.0;
  END IF;
  ...
END;
```